# Right syntax to auto-allocate an array

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I currently write a small Fortran code (90/03). I have a serious doubt with a simple syntax:

```
INTEGER :: BB
DOUBLE PRECISION,DIMENSION(10) :: CC
INTEGER,DIMENSION(:),ALLOCATABLE :: AA
BB=10
... (many things to declare double precision values in CC)
AA=pack([( i,i=1,BB )],mask=CC.GT.0.0) ! size(CC,1)=BB
```

Could I use this syntax? Do I need to allocate `AA` before call `pack`? Is there any risk of using this syntax?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is correct (except for the part that is left out where we cannot anything about it).

> Could I use this syntax?

Yes.

> Do I need to allocate `AA` before call `pack`?

No. Allocatable arrays will be automatically allocated and deallocated when out-of-scope. Regardless of whether the object on the right-hand is the result of any function or something else, e.g. an array of literals.

> Is there any risk of using this syntax?

I cannot think of anything risky here.

---

I guess you are confused about this line

```pascal
AA=pack([( i,i=1,BB )],mask=CC.GT.0.0)
```

I will try to explain it:

1. `[( i,i=1,BB )]` Builds an array of integers from 1 through 10 by an implied-do loop. Lets call this array B=B(i)
2. `mask=CC.GT.0.0` Only the elements B(i) of the previous array are choosen where CC(i)>0 holds.
3. `pack(...)` returns a 1-dimensional array of the previous result.

Comment: Thank you. The `pack` line was clear for me but I had a serious doubt concering the auto-allocation.

Comment: @guuk old compilers may need some extra options (like -frealloc-lhs for gfortran (< 4.8?) or -assume realloc_lhs for ifort <= 16(?)). Also, so-called "polymorphic assignment" may have issues for old gfortran. So to make it work even for old compilers, it may be safer to use allocate() explicitly; otherwise, I think auto-allocation works well for newer compilers by default (like gcc >= 8 or 9, though I have no experience for polymorphic assignment yet...)